# Ubuntu 20.10 freezes regularly after updating from 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.10

My Lenovo L480 had a 20.04 installed with few problems. After upgrading to 20.10, it freezes regularly. Means mouse pointer is frozen and no keyboard input produces any result. The only chance to recover is to switch it off and reboot. I tried 5.8.36 and 5.8.38 kernel but no real difference. I think it starts with wireless not working and ends with the mouse frozen. Sometimes it takes 5 minutes, sometimes 20.

This is my first Ubuntu update in the last 10 years that is so messed up. Is there any chance to avoid reinstall? I'll definitely avoid 20.10.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install the 5.10.8 Kernel but it didn't fix it. Since I switched to X session I had no freeze. Therefore I think it is related to Wayland.